# PHP How to select an array by name depending on other array value and assign contents to variables?

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

*Disclaimer: I'm quite new to PHP, so please be patient. I spent the whole day trying to figure this out, but I feel like I don't know the right methods or try the wrong way.*

---

### What I want to achieve

I let the user select **up to three** items from a multiple select input field in a form. I want to print all the information regarding those items, which are saved in separate arrays, to a pdf. The input field contains around 10 different options (let's say A1 to A10) and I fetch them in an array after form submission:

```js
$itemList = [
  [0] => A1,
  [1] => A2,   // optional
  [2] => A3    // optional
]
```

Now I have a separate array for each item, containing additional information (which might come from a database later):

```js
$infoA1 = [
  "info1" = "lorem",
  "info2" = "ipsum",
  "info3" = "dolor"
]

$infoA2 = [
  "info1" = "sit",
  "info2" = "amet",
  "info3" = "tatem"
]

$infoA3 ...
```

All of the info values should be assigned to variables for placement in a pdf so I have to check for how many items were selected in total and for each selected item I need to call a function like this:

```
function items1() {
  $pdf->SetXY(188.5,24);                 // *Note

  $pdf->Cell(17,4.7, $info1 ,0,2,'');    // $infoA1[0] = $info1
  $pdf->Cell(17,4.7, $info2 ,0,2,'');    // $infoA1[1] = $info1
  $pdf->Cell(17,4.7, $info3 ,0,2,'');    // $infoA1[2] = $info1
}
```

**Note: I can't have one function for all items, as the info variables for each selected item have to go to a different X and Y location on the pdf.*

### ...

### Here is my main question:

> How can I check which items are in the submitted `$itemList` array AND fetch the `$info array` with the same name to get the respective `info values` assigned to the placeholder variables which fill the pdf?

My thought was that I could somehow compare the names, like to get the `info array` which name contains the same value like the submitted item (e.g. "A1" in "$infoA1"). No luck with that so far, though.

Again, I suspect I'm using the wrong methods here, so any insights are highly appreciated. Also as I know that people here like to give answers only to the exact question provided: I am open to restructuring my current methods, if that suits the case of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out thanks to a combination of the solutions by @Mik and @kmoser, thank you two very much!

```php
// multilevel $info array holding data

$info = [
  'A1' => [
    "info1" => "lorem",
    "info2" => "ipsum",
    "info3" => "dolor",
  ],
  'A2' => [
    "info1" => "sit",
    "info2" => "amet",
    "info3" => "tatem",
  ],
  'A3' => [
    ...
];


// array of selected items submitted by form

$itemList = ["A1", "A2", "A3"];    // could also be ["A4", "A8", "A7"]


// map items to $info and coordinates

$map = [
  $itemList[0] => [ $info[$itemList[0]], 188.5, 24 ],
  $itemList[1] => [ $info[$itemList[1]], 188.5, 95.2 ],
  $itemList[2] => [ $info[$itemList[2]], 188.5, 167.7 ]
];


// call function for each submitted item
// also includes $pdf for use in function

foreach ($itemList as $item) {
  items($map[$item], $pdf);
}


// function gets mapped array and places data to X any Y coords

function items($item, $pdf) {
  $data = $item[0];
  $x = $item[1];
  $y = $item[2];

  $pdf->SetXY($x, $y);

  foreach ($data as $v) {
      $pdf->Cell(17,4.7, $v ,0,2,'');
  }
}


// this places the desired data to the pdf
// "lorem, ipsum, dolor" to (188.5/24), "sit, amet, tatem" to (188.5/95.2), and so on...
```

Well now, this is the complete solution, but I don't feel like taking credit for it, as this wouldn't exist without your answers. So, what is the fair thing to do here?

Also if there's things to improve here, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable variables.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
extract(${'info'.$itemList[0]});
var_dump($info1);
```

What this is doing is concatenating string with variable to make a variable variable and then the extract with turn your array keys into variable so you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

*Note: I can't have one function for all items, as the info variables for each selected item have to go to a different X and Y location on the pdf*

You actually *can* (and probably should) have one such function, which accepts three parameters: an array of data, an x coord, and a y coord. I've chosen to pass them in as a single array, but you can change that.

```
function items($a) {
    $data = $a[0];
    $x = $a[1];
    $y = $a[2];

    $pdf->SetXY($x, $y);

    foreach ( $data as $v ) {
        $pdf->Cell(17,4.7, $v ,0,2,'');
    }
}
```

(In your code you seemed to be placing everything at the same location: `$pdf->Cell(17,4.7, $info1 ,0,2,'')`. I kept it that way, but this just seems wrong.)

Then you need a way of mapping what's in `$itemList` to the `$infoA1` variables:

```
$map = [
    'A1' => [ $infoA1, 188.5, 24 ]
    'A2' => [ $infoA2, 355, 30 ], // Just making it up
    'A3' => [ $infoA3, 500, 50 ], // Just making it up
];
```

Finally, run through `$itemList` and look up the corresponding info in `$map` and pass it to the `items()` function:

```
foreach ( $itemList as $v ) {
    if ( $map[ $v ] ) {
        items( $map[ $v ] );
    }
}
```

This could be simplified and/or rewritten several ways but it all depends on what makes sense to you and how your data is structured.

Comment: Thanks! The `Cell()` attributes are height and width, that's why you probably think they are in the same place, but they get aligned below each other with the first one starting at X and Y, so that's fine (using TCPDF).

Comment: Great! If this answered your question sufficiently, please consider [marking it the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and/or upvoting it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! The final solution is a combination of yours and the one from @Mik (see my own answer). Let me know how to give you two proper credit, please, as this wouldn't exist without your help.

Comment: @VibeDesign [This page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255150/how-to-choose-between-multiple-correct-answers) explains how you can decide which answer to mark as accepted. (Ultimately it's your call.) In either case, you 're encouraged to [upvote any answers and comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

> *Note: I can't have one function for all items, as the info variables for each selected item have to go to a different X and Y location on
>   the pdf.

I guess, you can pass X and Y as arguments

I recommend to transform your variables into a multi dimensional array:

```php
$itemList = [
  [0] => 'A1',
  [1] => 'A2',   // optional
  [2] => 'A3',    // optional
];

$info = [
'A1' => [
  'x' => 188.5, 
  'y' => 24,
  "info1" => "lorem",
  "info2" => "ipsum",
  "info3" => "dolor",
],

'A2' = [
  'x' => 188.6, 
  'y' => 25,
  "info1" => "sit",
  "info2" => "amet",
  "info3" => "tatem",
],

'A3' ...
];
```

and so we can rewrite the function:

```php
function items($pdf, $info) {
  $pdf->SetXY($info['x'], $info['y']);

  $pdf->Cell(17,4.7, $info['info1'] ,0,2,'');
  $pdf->Cell(17,4.7, $info['info2'] ,0,2,'');
  $pdf->Cell(17,4.7, $info['info3'] ,0,2,'');
}
```

to use it like below:

```php
foreach ($itemList as $item) {
  items($pdf, $info[$item]);
}
```

so you have no need to check `$itemList`.

Comment: Thanks! Totally right about passing the X and Y values, but I also might have to adjust each `Cell()` item with individual height and width, that's why I think I still need individual functions. Also I get `$itemlist` from the form as a an associative array. How would I make this multidimensional and add the X and Y values?

Comment: Second thought: I might be fine using only one function, but `$itemList` can't contain the X and Y because they should be bound to the 1., 2. and 3. iteration of the function, regardless which selected item is passed (remember there are more than 3 items available to select). So I would have to assign X and Y to the `$itemList` array afterwards, but how?

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution by just taking the hardcoded array `$itemList` but it always fails in the function. Could there be some kind of scope issue here?

Comment: You right, it fails cause I forget to pass the `$pdf` into the function. Updated...

Comment: Additionally, I altered the whole code. Now you can get `$itemList` right from multiselect, so the function becomes even little shorter :) About another variables: I think you can store them all in subarrays of `$info`.

Comment: Works great, thank you alot! One last thing, I might have been not clear enough: X and Y should not be defined for each item but by their position in `$itemList`. Meaning whichever item is first in the array should go to X1,Y1 and whichever item is second in the array should go to X2, Y2 and so on. The user can select at max 3 items (out of more options). Do I check in the foreach for the 1st, 2nd and third iteration to assign the respective X and Y or is there a smarter way?

Comment: Can you give an example in code? I'm afraid I understand the case not very well

Comment: Not sure about code, but I try to clarify: I have maximum of three places where data should go on the PDF. So depending on, whether the user selects one, two or three items (out of many available options), the info for the first selected item should appear under X1/Y1, the info for the second selected item should appear under X2/Y2 and the third selected item should appear under X3/Y3. All X and Y values stay always the same, the only thing that can vary is which item is shown under which coordinates. Does that help?

Comment: X and Y of each item will be as two different inputs?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out using parts of the solution by @kmoser. Thank you for all your help!